# Plug and play system design?

Tags: architecture, system

How can i design a horizantal scalable system? My applications uses php(Laravel;1 website for customers an mobile application and other api),java (for port communication and insertion data to db),(activemq: data distirubiton queu),(mariadb or PostgreSQL i can use any db).

I want to design a plug and play system. How can make it on window os or linux distrubution?